# VSCode displays source code again in interactive window

Tags: visual-studio-code, interactive

[image: screenshot of the issue]

A question from a newbie here: when I run some python code in VSCode, there is always a display of source code in the interactive window. Thus I have to scroll all the way down before I can see the output. That makes the debug quite troublesome.

Please see the screenshot above. The code was displayed in the interactive window despite the editor just at left side over there. Any way to have VSCode, or maybe Jupyter extension, go directly to the output? (in my case starting from the 'Training Dataset shape......')

Comment: if you run your Python with a Task the output is shown in the terminal

Comment: While, that is not my case. It's lovely to see the output in interactive windows, I just don't want to see the code displayed again.